Can't login with AD user on Debian laptop with sssd config
I have this error message with sssd
juin 26 16:01:25 Computer253 sssd_be[21092]: Starting up juin 26 16:01:56 Computer253 sssd[20975]: Child [21092] ('xxx.intra.domain.fr':'%BE_xxx.intra.domain.fr') was terminated by own WATCHDOG. Consult corresponding logs to figure out the reason. 
sssd.conf
[sssd]
domains = xxx.intra.domain.fr
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/xxx.intra.domain.fr]
ad_domain = xxx.intra.domain.fr
ad_server = server1, server2, server3
access_provider =ad
auth_provider = ad
id_provider = ad
default_shell = /bin/bash
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
krb5_realm = XXX.INTRA.DOMAIN.FR
cache_credentials = True
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli 
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
use_fully_qualified_names = True
ldap_id_mapping = True
debug_level = 1
enumerate = True
ldap_user_uid_number = uidNumber
ldap_user_gid_number = gidNumber

krb5.conf
[libdefaults]
udp_preference_limit = 0
default_realm = XXX.INTRA.DOMAIN.FR
dns_lookup_realm = true
dns_lookup_kdc = true

This command works : root@Computer253:/var/log/sssd# getent passwd chucknorris@xxx.intra.domain.fr chucknorris@xxx.intra.domain.fr:*:7759189:7600513:NORRIS CHUCK:/home/chucknorris@xxx.intra.domain.fr:/bin/bash 
Part of sssd_xxx.intra.domain.fr.log
   *  (2024-06-26 17:01:35): [be[xxx.intra.domain.fr]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [whenChanged]
   *  (2024-06-26 17:01:35): [be[xxx.intra.domain.fr]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [uSNChanged]
   *  (2024-06-26 17:01:35): [be[xxx.intra.domain.fr]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [groupType]
   *  (2024-06-26 17:01:35): [be[xxx.intra.domain.fr]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x2000): ldap_search_ext called, msgid = 14
   *  (2024-06-26 17:01:35): [be[xxx.intra.domain.fr]] [sdap_op_add] (0x2000): New operation 14 timeout 60
   *  (2024-06-26 17:01:35): [be[xxx.intra.domain.fr]] [sdap_process_result] (0x2000): Trace: sh[0x559ddc9815f0], connected[1], ops[0x559decf99a80], ldap[0x559ddc89f210]
   *  (2024-06-26 17:01:35): [be[xxx.intra.domain.fr]] [sdap_process_result] (0x2000): Trace: end of ldap_result list
   *  (2024-06-26 17:01:35): [be[xxx.intra.domain.fr]] [sdap_op_timeout] (0x1000): Issuing timeout [ldap_opt_timeout] for message id 3
   *  (2024-06-26 17:01:35): [be[xxx.intra.domain.fr]] [sdap_op_destructor] (0x1000): Abandoning operation 3
   *  (2024-06-26 17:01:35): [be[xxx.intra.domain.fr]] [generic_ext_search_handler] (0x0020): sdap_get_generic_ext_recv failed: [110]: Connexion terminée par expiration du délai d'attente [ldap_search_timeout]
********************** BACKTRACE DUMP ENDS HERE *********************************

(2024-06-26 17:01:35): [be[xxx.intra.domain.fr]] [ad_get_slave_domain_done] (0x0020): Unable to lookup slave domain data [110]: Connexion terminée par expiration du délai d'attente
********************** PREVIOUS MESSAGE WAS TRIGGERED BY THE FOLLOWING BACKTRACE:
   *  (2024-06-26 17:01:35): [be[xxx.intra.domain.fr]] [sdap_search_bases_ex_done] (0x0400): Receiving data from base [dc=intra,dc=domain,dc=fr]
   *  (2024-06-26 17:01:35): [be[xxx.intra.domain.fr]] [ad_get_slave_domain_done] (0x0020): Unable to lookup slave domain data [110]: Connexion terminée par expiration du délai d'attente

Part of sssd.log
   *  (2024-06-26 16:59:56): [sssd] [sbus_senders_add] (0x2000): Inserting identity of sender [sssd.pac]: 0
   *  (2024-06-26 16:59:56): [sssd] [monitor_sbus_RegisterService] (0x0100): Received ID registration: (pac,1)
   *  (2024-06-26 16:59:56): [sssd] [mark_service_as_started] (0x0200): Marking pac as started.
   *  (2024-06-26 16:59:56): [sssd] [mark_service_as_started] (0x0400): All services have successfully started, creating pid file
   *  (2024-06-26 16:59:56): [sssd] [notify_startup] (0x0400): Sending startup notification to systemd
   *  (2024-06-26 16:59:56): [sssd] [sbus_issue_request_done] (0x0400): sssd.monitor.RegisterService: Success
   *  (2024-06-26 16:59:56): [sssd] [sbus_dispatch] (0x4000): Dispatching.
   *  (2024-06-26 17:00:01): [sssd] [services_startup_timeout] (0x0400): Handling timeout
   *  (2024-06-26 17:00:37): [sssd] [mt_svc_exit_handler] (0x1000): SIGCHLD handler of service xxx.intra.domain.fr called
   *  (2024-06-26 17:00:37): [sssd] [svc_child_info] (0x0020): Child [24897] ('xxx.intra.domain.fr':'%BE_xxx.intra.domain.fr') was terminated by own WATCHDOG
********************** BACKTRACE DUMP ENDS HERE *********************************

(2024-06-26 17:01:58): [sssd] [svc_child_info] (0x0020): Child [24968] ('xxx.intra.domain.fr':'%BE_xxx.intra.domain.fr') was terminated by own WATCHDOG
   *  ... skipping repetitive backtrace ...
(2024-06-26 17:02:49): [sssd] [svc_child_info] (0x0020): Child [24994] ('xxx.intra.domain.fr':'%BE_xxx.intra.domain.fr') was terminated by own WATCHDOG
   *  ... skipping repetitive backtrace ...
(2024-06-26 17:03:30): [sssd] [svc_child_info] (0x0020): Child [25008] ('xxx.intra.domain.fr':'%BE_xxx.intra.domain.fr') was terminated by own WATCHDOG
   *  ... skipping repetitive backtrace ...
(2024-06-26 17:04:21): [sssd] [svc_child_info] (0x0020): Child [25016] ('xxx.intra.domain.fr':'%BE_xxx.intra.domain.fr') was terminated by own WATCHDOG

sytemctl status sssd
● sssd.service - System Security Services Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/sssd.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-06-26 17:06:53 CEST; 2min 10s ago
   Main PID: 25183 (sssd)
      Tasks: 5 (limit: 37992)
     Memory: 703.4M
        CPU: 1min 33.427s
     CGroup: /system.slice/sssd.service
             ├─25183 /usr/sbin/sssd -i --logger=files
             ├─25190 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_nss --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
             ├─25191 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_pam --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
             ├─25192 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_pac --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
             └─25276 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_be --domain xxx.intra.domain.fr --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files

juin 26 17:06:53 Computer253 sssd[25183]: Starting up
juin 26 17:06:53 Computer253 sssd_be[25189]: Starting up
juin 26 17:06:53 Computer253 sssd_pac[25192]: Starting up
juin 26 17:06:53 Computer253 sssd_nss[25190]: Starting up
juin 26 17:06:53 Computer253 sssd_pam[25191]: Starting up
juin 26 17:06:53 Computer253 systemd[1]: Started sssd.service - System Security Services Daemon.
juin 26 17:07:44 Computer253 sssd[25183]: Child [25189] ('xxx.intra.domain.fr':'%BE_xxx.intra.domain.fr') was terminated by own WATCHDOG. Consult corresponding logs to figure out the reason.
juin 26 17:07:44 Computer253 sssd_be[25241]: Starting up
juin 26 17:08:15 Computer253 sssd[25183]: Child [25241] ('xxx.intra.domain.fr':'%BE_xxx.intra.domain.fr') was terminated by own WATCHDOG. Consult corresponding logs to figure out the reason.
juin 26 17:08:15 Computer253 sssd_be[25276]: Starting up

When I try to login with AD user "Chuck Norris" for example, it doesn't work. I have to write user@domain, and password ok but it doesn't go on user desktop. I stay on logon screen. Homedir is created with domain group and user@domain user with 700 on dir.
I'm not sure if my sssd.conf is set correctly

i tried with sudo login user@domain, it is very long and ends by timeout error

Can you set [domain/XXXX] debuglevel=6 or 9 (max) and take a look at the log after another attempt? Perhaps ldap connection is malfunctioning, due to AD server misconfiguration or maybe wrong attribute storing the unix password.
